# Historical recordings of ex tempore contemporary Latin used in university lectures?

Tags: contemporary-latin, history, resource-request, academic-latin

Are there any historical recordings of fluent *ex tempore* Latin used in university lectures, such as for theology or philosophy courses, in academic events, or in scholastic disputations? I'm looking for audio between circa 1900 and 1960.

The closest I've been able to find to this is [Wyoming Catholic College](http://www.wyomingcatholiccollege.com)'s Dr. Jeremy Holmes [reading St. Thomas Aquinas's *Compendium Theologiæ* and explaining its grammar *ex tempore* in Latin](http://www.archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%22Jeremy%20Holmes%22%20subject%3A%22Latin%22&sort=publicdate) (source: [Latin resources here](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~aversa/latin/#resources)), but it is fairly recent (2010).

Answer (score 10):

Professor Wilifried Stroh's [lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3U5kjdOM5j8) on the history of Latin literature and [on other subjects](http://stroh.userweb.mwn.de/main21.html) are incredibly entertaining, learned, and eloquent. I don't know when he made them, but since he was born in 1950 I doubt it was before 1960, unfortunately. Still, they're very worth listening to.